# How to use trig to spawn an object in "front" of the player object

Tags: java, 2d, trigonometry, direction

What I am trying to convey in the title, is that there is a player on the screen and, using the direction variable and trigonometry, he is "looking" in a direction. I need to spawn an object right in front of him. And by spawn, I mean create an object with the x and y coordinates matching the location of the spot in "front" of the player.

The code for this is something difficult. I'm unable to understand, without more information or learning more trig, what I need to do to get this to work.

Basically this is what I have, it creates a bullet and another line of code adds it to a list to be drawn to the screen. What I need to know is how to spawn the "bullet" object in the correct x & y coordinates. This is what I have so far. I can assume there is something more I need to add to the x and y variables, but I don't know what that is.

```
Bullet b = new Bullet((int)x/2+(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction))), (int)y/2 + (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction))), "/img/bullet.png",  direction, weapon);
```

Comment: @Downvoter, may I inquire as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a vector pointing in a direction where you want the object spawned.

```
x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + startX
y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + startY
```

Normalize it, and then scale it to your liking.

[Here's a simple demo to illustrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj2Gd/4/)

*p.s*

`radius` here is just an initial uniform displacement from the spawn point.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what radius and angle would be? Is the angle the x/y coordinate of the object spawn?

Comment: I'll create a jsfiddle for you to illustrate ;)

Comment: @Levi Check the link again, I updated it with a neat demo, It should help you.

Comment: Nice demo. +1 for effort.

Comment: Sorry about how long I took, been at work. @iccthedral I love the demo, its pretty cool. I never learned javascript, but I get most of it. Here is something though, what does Normalization and Scaling do exactly? By name scaling sounds like it is making the object bigger/smaller.

Comment: Nevermind. Finally played around with your code enough (after porting it to java) to understand how it works. This should be perfect, thanks for the trig help!

Comment: @Levi Awesome, but if you still need an explanation just bump this conversation. I'll try to help, maybe not immediately but within 2-3 days for sure. Have fun programming buddy.

Comment: Actually, I would like an explanation of polarToCart(...); as it seems (from your fiddle) that is what I'm after. However, when I implement it, the character can turn and fire at the same time, but the bullet object is spawned around him, not in front of him. There are a few angles that spawn bullets correctly, but not enough.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you understood [Proportionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29), but it is basically this: if you multiply x and y for the same number, you will get farther away from the current position. Of course that depends on the signals, but the simplest way is this: supposing that x and y are two positive numbers, let's say x=1 and y=1, then, if you multiply both by a positive number, let's say 3, then the final numbers (x=3 and y=3) you will have a "bullet" in the coordinates 3,3 that is right in front of the actor, which is in the position 1,1. Again, I am assuming a lot of things and ignoring a bunch of other ones, such as position of camera, perspective, etc.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying; but the player object can be turned in any direction and from there I need to spawn him in front of the character.